# Error in creating tables in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

The code for tables i used in beamer is as follows :

```
         \begin{center}
         \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
         \hline
         Risk&Meaning&Example\\
         \hline
          Project Risk&Affect the project schedule or resources&Loss of anexperienced designer\\
          \hline
          Product Risk&Affect the quality or performance of the software being developed&Failure of a purchased component to perform as expected.\\
          \hline
          Business Risk&Affect the organisation developing or procuring the software&A competitor introducing a new product is a business risk
           \end{tabular}
           \end{center}
```

How to correct it?
[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: No error here. Your table is simply too wide to fit on the page. You should consider replacing your `r` column specifications by `p{.25\textwidth}` or something like that, in order to effect line breaks in cells and make the table fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just trying to fit too much on a single line in the tabular. One way to correct this is to set up a set width for the widest columns and to allow TeX to break the lines as it would with regular paragraphs outside of tables.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|p{.3\textwidth}|p{.3\textwidth}|}
     \hline
     Risk& \hfill Meaning& \hfill Example\\
     \hline
      Project Risk&Affect the project schedule or resources&Loss of anexperienced designer\\
      \hline
      Product Risk&Affect the quality or performance of the software being developed&Failure of a purchased component to perform as expected.\\
      \hline
      Business Risk&Affect the organisation developing or procuring the software&A competitor introducing a new product is a business risk\\\hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular on slide with p{width} columns]